# Как реализовать возвращение назад во фрагменте, запущенном из адаптера RecyclerView другого фрагмента

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-button, fragment-manager

Мне нужно, чтобы в запущенном фрагменте была возможность возвращения в предыдущий фрагмент:

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Сам фрагмент запускается в RecyclerView адаптере (если вдруг это важно)

Я пробовал реализовать возвращение назад, добавляя `addToBackStack(null)` в код запуска фрагмента:

```
    val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
    activity.supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment).
        addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
```

К сожалению, это не работает (а при использовании `commitNow()` и вовсе вылетает ошибка)

В данный момент мне не принципиально, делать это через кнопку или способом, подобным тому, что приведён в коде выше, главное, чтобы работало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите вернуть пользователя на предыдущею страницу, то вы можете вызвать метод `onBackPressed()`

Comment: пока что не очень понял, как его реализовать (свою попытку добавил в текст вопроса)

Comment: У вас есть открытый Fragment, вы хотите его закрыть и показать предыдущею страницу, для этого вы можете в Fragment создать кнопку, повесить обработчик и при клике вызывать метод requireActivity().onBackPressed() Докуметнация https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#onBackPressed()